# Can't mount external HDD. Device listed at lsusb but doesn't appear at /dev

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, mount, dev

Device works at Windows but doesn't appear at /dev. How can I mount it?

So let's go to the infos...

uname -a:

Linux deeptought 3.13.0-30-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 9 22:45:01 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Being new in this forum I can only post 2 links, so this will be kinda messy... sorry =/

At [this](http://pastebin.com/G7TeiRm3) link you'll find the output of lsusb, mount, /var/log/kern.log and /var/cache/powertop/saved_results.powertop

That's all the relevant information I could think of... please let me know if I can contribute with something else...

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: What file system is the disk? NTFS, Fat32 etc?

Comment: @BigChris Shouldn't matter...there could be NO filesystem, but the device should still show up in `/dev`.

Comment: What exactly is the device (Part number, preferably)?

Comment: Its an external HDD that plays videos and connects itself to an TV by HDMI.. It's called [Iomega ScreenPlay MX HD Media Player](http://www.iomega.com/support/manuals/mediaplayer/scrnplymx/en/main.html)
P/N:31915000
Model: SPDHDMX

Comment: Unplug the disk in Ubuntu, do `dmesg | tail`, plug it back in and do `dmesg | tail` again and paste the second tail up. Could do with seeing the messages for that device.

Comment: Could you please include the output for `cat /var/log/dmesg|grep "sd "`

Comment: The requested informations are [here](http://pastebin.com/4bZqmnXx)

Comment: Could you please try just using a different USB plug, to see whether the output of dmesg changes at all?

Answer (score -2):

```
sudo blkid
```

(your device is /dev/sdx)

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/here
sudo mount /dev/sdx /mnt/here
```